# Windows generating more heat than Linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, laptop, battery

I have two dualboot machines with one having Windows/Ubuntu and another having Windows/Manjaro, and on both I can clearly feel that when *Windows* is running they generate a lot more heat, draining the battery faster and generally getting pretty hot on the lap, even when I`m not doing anything (CPU at 1-2%). It's hot constantly.

However, when then they run the Unix counterpart (Ubuntu/Manjaro), they dont't get nearly as hot, the battery life almost doubles and the fans barely spin, even when pushing the machine with multiple programs. In fact, when I don't do anything on the machines, they cool down so much you can barely tell they're on.

Is this an general issue with Windows, or am I missing something here?

Thanks for any answers!

Comment: Try setting the power plan to Balanced or Power Saver instead of High Performance. Also make sure you have installed the correct drivers

Comment: It is not a general issue with Windows. My Windows machines run cool and use very little power,

Comment: Have you ever checked what happens if you leave Windows running for some two hours? I've seen some systems needing to set something up or whatever, and they'd do that until they settled after one or two hours, not to bother again.

Comment: I'd also check energy conservation settings and processes for CPU and disk activity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some digging and a fresh install of Windows, I finally figured it out!

Looks like when ThrottleStop is running, for whatever reason it sticks to Max non-turbospeed *all the time*, and this obviously heats it up massively.

For anyone wondering: I know it sounds funny if you don't know what the program ThrottleStop does and only hear it by the name. The thing is: If you set it right, it should let you adjust the speed accordingly and even allow underclock or undervolt, thus reducing heat. However, on mine it's broken and sticks to max speeds all the time.

Letting Windows alone manage power settings (Balanced or Power Saver) + debloating Windows 11 with scripts found on GitHub makes a whole lot of a difference.

Now it is dropping sub 1GHz sometimes and not even warm to the touch if you let it idle.

Thanks for all the answers nonetheless!

Answer (score 0):

Apart from using Task Manager (taskmgr) to see running processes, you can also go to Start-> type "msconfig" this will show the processes executed at startup and the services, so you can select only what you want.
Go to Start-> type "task Scheduler" A lot of applications have agents that run in the background (including Adobe Reader), most of the time you don't need those tasks. You can erase them except for those corresponding to your antivirus.
By default, windows 10 sends a lot of data to Microsoft servers, Look for tutorialas like this https://www.computerworld.com/article/3622001/how-to-protect-privacy-windows-10.html or this one https://www.express.co.uk/life-style/science-technology/603524/Windows-10-Microsoft-Key-Logger-Record-Privacy to configure your privacy (in short: go to Settings->Privacy, peruse everything and disable what you don't need). Also, windows 10 comes with a lot of software you won't use. Uninstall it. This can take up to an hour, but is worth the effort.